# Inequality constraints in Lagrangian

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

[image]

I was reading Lagrangian multipliers . In the above text I can't understand why $\lambda \ge 0 $ for $g(x)\ge0$ and vice versa . Can anyone give me the explanation to this ?

Comment: It looks like you'd want to penalize if the inequality condition isn't kept. I suppose you use the Lagrangian for maximization and use a plus sign, that is something of the form: $\max f(x) + \lambda g(x)$. In that case, note that if the inequality is $g(x)\ge0$, then in the lagrangian optimization it never adds anything when $g(x)<0$, since then $\lambda g(x)<0$, which decreases the total. So in that optimization $g(x)\ge0$ is automatically encoded. The other cases are similar. This is a comment for a reason, so let's see if someone can give a real answer.